# Create millions of records for ActiveRecord test

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, greenplum

In Ruby, I have a test that's a subclass of `ActiveSupport::TestCase` and access a table through an `ActiveRecord` subclass in a Postgres (actually Greenplum) database. For a particular test I need to populate the table with on the order of a million rows, but I don't really care what's in there. I could do something like

```
for i in 1...1000000 do
  MyTable.create(:column1 => 'value', :column2 => 'value')
end
```

but this will take a long time to run. I could make it a little faster by wrapping it in a transaction so that `create` won't create a new one every time, but that will only save so much time.

Is there some nice way to do this so that I don't have to execute a lot of inserts of bogus values into the table?

(Note: stubbing things out to try to pretend that the table contains a million records won't work because I later on need to interact with the actual rows; for this particular test I just don't care what they are)

Comment: If you can drop into raw SQL you could use this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR

Comment: Using `for` is an anti-pattern. It simply calls `each`, so it makes more sense (and follows OO patterns) to do `(1...1000000).each do ... end`. Or even better simply `1000000.times do ... end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run all that in a simple query like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) 
SELECT 'value1', 'value2' 
FROM generate_series(1,1000000);
```

This should populate database pretty fast. It takes 2 seconds my laptop.

Comment: Hooray for [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES)! That's such a useful PostgreSQL feature.